# Executing array of requests fails with "Error: done() called multiple times". Mapping over array of requests is not firing requests

Tags: javascript, promise, mocha.js, supertest

I have run into an interesting problem, I need to execute a bunch of requests, the order in which they execute does not matter.
I am using the following libraries on this code, Mocha, Supertest (to fire RESTful requests), and Asynquence to help with the promise chain.

So what I have done is to create an array of functions, with each function containing a POST request. My reasoning was to map over this array and perform a '**function.apply()**;' to execute the requests but that is not working for some reason, so I shifted to use Asynquence, which is successfully firing the requests, **however** Mocha is failing with the following error: "**Error: done() called multiple times**".
Here is my code:

The first thing that I do is to use a map to create an array of these using the 'data' that I am going to send:

```
function queryGenerator(cookie, data, done, msg) {
          return function() {
            return request('www.myurl.com')
            .post('/endpoint/sample')
            .set('cookie', cookie)
            .send(data)
            .expect(200)
            .end(function(err, res) {
              if(err) { console.log('Error when posting to preferences setup on:', data); return done(err) };
              done(msg);
            })
          }
        }
```

Then I have a function to apply these:

```
function executeFunction(fn) {
          return fn.apply();
        }
```

So trying this does not work:

```
collectionOfRequestsToExectute.map(executeFunction);
```

The requests do not seem to be firing all.
However, the following works, in the sense that all requests are executed HOWEVER I get the following error: "**Error: done() called multiple times**" being thrown by Mocha.

```
it("Turn all of the other emails off", function(done) {
          const collectionOfRequestsToTurnOff = [nationalJobsPayloadTurnOff, hiringAlertsPayloadTurnOff, professionalsLikeYouPayloadTurnOff, newJobsPayloadTurnOff];
          const functionsToExec = collectionOfRequestsToTurnOff.map(function(data) {
            return queryGenerator(cookie, data, done);
          });

          ASQ('apply each request in array').all.apply(null, functionsToExec)
          .val(function() {
            var messages = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
            console.log('MESSAGES:', messages);
          })
          .or(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
          })
        })
```

Please help!
I would like to avoid having to have to fire each of this requests one by one.
Thanks in advance!

**Edit**: as answered below, by [Roamer-1888](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3478010/roamer-1888) (thanks a lot) the problem was that I was passing Mocha's done to the queryGenerator, which in turn was calling done() multiple times.

I have another question, I tried to map over the collection of functions to execute using the solution's example to rename the promise on the query generator to 'dunn' (see code below) but when I do that I get an "**Uncaught TypeError: dunn is not a function**"

```
functionsToExecute.map(function(fn) {
   return fn.apply();
})
```

I feel using a map is more readable, and I avoid having to use the `ASQ('msg').all.apply(null,functionsToExec)...`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is, you have two `done()`s going on, Mocha's and ASQ's.

As written, the second attempt passes Mocha's done to `queryGenerator()`, which is incorrect - Mocha's `done` will indeed be called multiple times.

On calling `ASQ(...).all.apply(null, functionsToExec)`, each function in `functionsToExec` will be passed ASQ's `(done, msg)` automatically (they are "revealed").

To fix, it appears that you need simply to :

- pass only `(cookie, data)` to `queryGenerator` - these params become trapped in a closure.
- write queryGenerator's inner function to accept the revealed args `(done, msg)`

To make it clear which `done` is which I have spelled ASQ's done as `dunn` (you can name the revealed args however you choose).

```
function queryGenerator(cookie, data) { // <<<<<< (cookie, data) here
    return function(dunn, msg) { // <<<<<< (dunn, msg) here
        return request('www.myurl.com')
        .post('/endpoint/sample')
        .set('cookie', cookie)
        .send(data)
        .expect(200)
        .end(function(err, res) {
            if(err) {
                console.log('Error when posting to preferences setup on:', data); 
                dunn(err.message); // return not required
            };
            dunn(msg);
        });
    }
}

it("Turn all of the other emails off", function(done) {
    const collectionOfRequestsToTurnOff = [nationalJobsPayloadTurnOff, hiringAlertsPayloadTurnOff, professionalsLikeYouPayloadTurnOff, newJobsPayloadTurnOff];
    const functionsToExec = collectionOfRequestsToTurnOff.map(function(data) {
        return queryGenerator(cookie, data);
    });
    ASQ('apply each request in array').all.apply(null, functionsToExec).val(function() {
        var messages = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        console.log('MESSAGES:', messages);
        done(messages);
    }).or(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
        done(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! It was an issue of the promise chain as you pointed out. Changing the promise name change for the ASQ section solved the problem.

Comment: Also, Roamer-1888, do you have any insight as to why if I try to map over the collections of functions to execute, e.g. (functionsToExecute.map(function(fn) {
                return fn.apply();
              })) I get the following error: "Uncaught TypeError: dunn is not a function" ?
I feel this is more readable than the ASQ('msg').all.apply(null, functionsToExec)...

Comment: As written `queryGenerator()` is written specifically for use with `ASQ().all`, which reveals `dunn` and `msg` to the passed functions. Therefore `functionsToExecute.map()` is not a simple substitute for `ASQ().all`.